# Crear div para cada posición del array

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito que cada todas las líneas del array se agregue a mi html siendo individualmente contenida en un div, esto cada vez que yo hago click en div5 (y se ira agregando tantas veces como haga click, ahora mismo funciona a falta de los divs para cada línea que no se ponerlo.

```js
const five = document.getElementById("div5");

five.addEventListener("click", showDivByDiv);


let dataset = [
    1,
    4,
    5,
    7
]

/* For Div5 (Show div's array) */

function showDivByDiv() {
    
    for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
        five.innerHTML += dataset[i];
      };
}
```

```html
        <!-- Box 5 -->
        <div class="item" id="div5">
            <h4>5</h4>
            <p>Click para mostrar un div por cada elemento del array "dataset" con el contenido de la posición</p>
            <!-- Aquí los divs -->

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo unico que te falto es poner las etiquetas div correspondientes. Para hacer esto se usan template strings, donde puedes convinar cadenas de texto con javascript.

Reemplaza la linea

```
five.innerHTML += dataset[i];
```

Con la linea

```
five.innerHTML += `<div>${dataset[i]}</div>`;
```

Otra forma mas moderna de hacerlo seria:

```
function showDivByDiv() {
      let divs = dataset.map(el => `<div>${el}</div>`).join("")
      five.innerHTML += divs
}
```

Con el metodo map() generas el mismo array con menos lineas de codigo y de una forma funcional. (el join es para sacar las comas)

Comment: @hernás Garcia muchas gracias